# Powershell Start-Process create new variables

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use Start-Process command to invoke another session of powershell. But I want to have the windows size of this new powershell to be small so I am trying to pass the following arguments

```
$arguments[0] +=  "New-Variable -Name host1 -Value (Get-Host)"
$arguments[1] +=  "$aff = $host1.UI.RawUI"
$arguments[2] +=  "$wff = $aff.WindowSize"
$arguments[3] +=  "$wff.Width = 10"
$arguments[4] +=  "$wff.Height = 10"
$arguments[5] +=  "$aff.WindowSize = $wff"
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Any help will be highly appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: I've never tried to do this my self, but I would imagine that instead of passing variables from out side the session, you would want code to run inside the session to make the change.

Comment: no I dont want to pass the variable I want to create the variable because as you can see I need to set the variable paramaters and change the window size

Comment: So this: "New-Variable -Name host1 -Value (Get-Host)" will not create a variable named host1 if you are passing it in as an argument. It will be passed as a string literal. No execution happens on arguments as they are passed in.

Comment: Ok, But then is there any other way to do it. Can I reset the window size without creating these variables.

Comment: You can pass in the sizes that you want the window to be then have the new session run a script that resizes using those values.

Comment: I will try but can u give me a small demo example so that I will understand it better.

Comment: To be honest with you i've never tried it myself and I don't have the time to really work it out right now. Someone in chat might be able to help.

Comment: Ok no problem thanks for the guidance really appreciated I will dig deeper :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make the new PowerShell hidden?

```
Start-Process powershell -WindowStyle Hidden ...
```

Also, PowerShell variables won't transfer from one PowerShell session to another spawned one.  If you need that behavior, then store your info in environment variables e.g.:

```
$env:Width = '10'
$env:Height = '10'
```

Comment: Hi Keith, thank for the answer- no the -WindowStyle Hidden does not work when you open a powershell session as a different user from the current user who is logged in :-( . But the env variable idea is something that I will give a try immediately- thanks for the help

Comment: @ajax FWIW using `WindowStyle` does work in this situation using PowerShell V3 e.g. `start-process powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Credential $cred -ArgumentList '-Command "& { get-date > c:\temp\foo.txt}"'` creates C:\temp\foo.txt with the current date without a PowerShell console ever appearing.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. but sadly i have to work on powershell 2.0